# Firebase host:i can deploy but how to hide source code

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have deployed my website by using Firebase host but when i do Right Click > View page source: i can see source code and my firebase Project information

So How can i hide it ; Will i have to use Node.js ? or Cloud functions ?

i have tried node's http npm
const http = require ('http');

```
onRequest();
function onRequest (req , res){
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(3000);
console.log("Success");
}
```

but it does not help

i am really confused please help me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide some stuff from your users you will need to hide it in the server side. So with Firebase, you can use the Firebase Cloud Function. They accept nodejs, python and typescript. If you want to store variable in your website, then use the database.

After that, make sure to set your database rules safely.